# Does Google Docs support sequential fields?

Tags: google-docs

In MS Word, you can have sequential form fields, for instance, a document could have a field like `Chapter {N}`, where the actual number increases sequentially, incrementing after each occurence.

This is very handy when you have a 75 chapter novel and one day you combine chapters 2 and 3 into one chapter, and then the rest of the chapters automatically renumber. Doing this by hand would, of course, be very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs hasn't a feature similar to MS Word fields but it could be extended by using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs) and / the new [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api). Developers could use this tools to create add-ons and they could be installed from the Tools menu and from the G Suite Marketplace.